# Target Exception throws by media player on javaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, mp3

I'm writing a simple application with java and trying to play sounds but I can't get it to work when I create the Media object it throws 
`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` , the file name is correct , and i tried the full file path name and i get the same error 
my code is : 
`

```
public class Try extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane () ; 
        Button b = new Button("click here ") ; 
        Media m = new Media ("music.mp3");
        MediaPlayer md = new MediaPlayer(m) ; 


        b.setOnAction(e -> {
        md.play();
            System.out.println("clicked");
    });

        pane.getChildren().add(b) ; 
        Scene s = new Scene(pane , 300 ,300 ) ; 
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
```

i tried `.wav` files and get same error . 
the full error :
`

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == 'music.mp3'
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:218)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at ttry.Try.start(Try.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ttry.Try
`
```

Comment: start by giving a full path to your `.mp3` file - right now it looks like the file may not be found/loaded as `Media`

Comment: The constructor of `Media` expects a URI string. Regardless of the presence of the file a scheme needs to be part of the URI. (`file:` in case the file is stored in the file system directly)

Comment: An important thing to note about `InvocationTargetException` is that it is ***rarely*** (if ever) the actual root cause of the problem. Instead, you need to look at the lines in your StackTrace (the long error messages) that start with `"Caused by:"`. That will lead you to the actual cause of the problem. In this case, it is: `IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == 'music.mp3'`.